# Get difference between two times that are in hh:mm format and greater than 24 hours

Tags: php, date

I want to get the difference in two times that are in hh:mm format. I am using this function

```
<?php
function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime) {
    $firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
    $lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);
    $timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;
    return $timeDiff;
}

echo (timeDiff("10:00","20:00")/60)/60;
?>
```

The issue is that it works perfectly if I have hours less than 24. But I need it to work for upto 60 hours. Like `60:00 - 02:25 should give me 57:35` and `60:00 - 00:00 should give me 60:00`. Where are I doing wrong?

Comment: 60:00 is not a valid time format value

Comment: `strtotime` doesn't work with that format with values higher than **24:59** (which is weird in itself). You'll need to break the string apart into hours and minutes, and calculate them individually.

Comment: You might have an easier time if you used [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only work with hours + minutes, then you can just calculate the timestamp yourself, something like that:

```
function calculateSeconds($time) {
    $timeParts = explode(':', $time);
    return (int)$timeParts[0] * 3600 + (int)$timeParts[1] * 60;
}
```

and then use it in your function

```
function timeDiff($firstTime, $lastTime) {
    return calculateSeconds($lastTime) - calculateSeconds($firstTime);
}
```

Comment: echo echo timeDiff('00:00','60:00'); giving me 216000 ?? I need hh:mm

Comment: this is the difference in seconds. if you need to format it, just do it: `$hours = $diff / 3600; $minutes = $diff / 60;`

Comment: I did this

function timeDiff($firstTime, $lastTime) {
    $time_diff = calculateSeconds($lastTime) - calculateSeconds($firstTime);
    $hours = $time_diff / 3600; $minutes = $time_diff / 60;
    return $hours.":".$minutes;
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gmdate()` function as bellow.

```
function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime) {
    $a_split = explode(":", $firstTime);
    $b_split = explode(":", $lastTime);
    $a_stamp = mktime($a_split[0], $a_split[1]);
    $b_stamp = mktime($b_split[0], $b_split[1]);
    if($a_stamp > $b_stamp)
    {
        $diff = $a_stamp - $b_stamp; //69600
    }else{
        $diff = $b_stamp - $a_stamp; //69600
    }
    $min = gmdate("i", $diff); 
    $d_hours = gmdate("d", $diff)==1 ? 0 :  gmdate("d", $diff)*12 ;
    $hours = $d_hours + gmdate("H", $diff) ;
    echo $hours . ':' . $min; // 56:12:12
}
timeDiff("35:05", "01:45");
```